# FloatingActionButton is not pinning in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

I want to show `FloatingActionButton` bottom-right every time (while scrolling too). But when I used it with `RecyclerView` it doesn't show on the  `RecyclerView`. It is shown under the  `RecyclerView`.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/kitapListeRw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/kitapEkleBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />

 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

How to show FAB bottom-right and not under the `RecyclerView` every time?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but try wrapping your `RecyclerView` in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: I want to pin FAB. Even though scrolling recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting bottom and end constraints to parent

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/kitapEkleBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
```

Comment: Seems like this is the way to go +1

Comment: @Zain first of all thank u for editting. But unfortunately not pinned.

Comment: @emreturka thanks for your comment, can you please tell if you set `mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener`? .. maybe you accidentally hide the fab on it

Comment: @emreturka What unexpected result you get by this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I solved the problem. I made a mistake building. I put floatingaction button in my main layout. Because there is a drawerlayout.